# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'card1' in 'field list' in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with my Mysql script. Here is the code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MTG;
USE MTG;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abzan
    (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        card1 VARCHAR(100),
        card2 VARCHAR(100),
        card3 VARCHAR(100),
        card4 VARCHAR(100),
        card5 VARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT INTO abzan (id,card1,card2,card3,card4,card5)
    VALUES (1,'Warden of the First Tree','Anafenza the Foremost','Siege Rhino','Hangarback Walker','Fleecemane Lion');
```

Every time I try to execute this Script, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'card1' in 'field list'
```

I already searched in Google and many forums like this, and I tried many solutions, but none of them worked. Once I read that the problem is a character which comes from copy and paste from other programs, I typed everything new, but it didn't help. I don't know what is wrong with my code. I'm glad if anybody could help me.

Comment: are you sure you are targeting the right database?

Comment: Record inserted....check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f05f9/3

Comment: Do you have rights to create the database? And was the database created?

Comment: you didn't permit your database.grant all privileges on db_name.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password';

Comment: and BTW, you probably shouldn't have cards in columns. you should be having them in rows

Comment: Is INTEGER  a datatype in MYSQL? Use INT